# how to make the values of dictionary appear in alphabetical order

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
{'song': 1, 'like': 1, 'most': 1, 'neer': 1, 'hides': 1, 'live': 1, 'yours': 1, 'come': 2, 'not': 1, 'rage': 1, 'deserts': 1, 'be': 2, 'graces': 1, 'metre': 1, 'rights': 1, 'tomb': 1, 'stretched': 1, 'verse': 1, 'write': 1, 'the': 2, 'beauty': 1, 'all': 1, 'should': 2, 'it': 3, 'rhyme': 1, 'is': 1, 'this': 1, 'in': 4, 'earthly': 1, 'numbers': 1, 'to': 2, 'if': 2, 'my': 3, 'yet': 1, 'less': 1, 'would': 1, 'life': 1, 'an': 1, 'alive': 1, 'number': 1, 'a': 2, 'child': 1, 'say': 1, 'tongue': 1, 'heavenly': 1, 'knows': 1, 'men': 1, 'could': 1, 'half': 1, 'so': 1, 'parts': 1, 'their': 1, 'high': 1, 'with': 2, 'believe': 1, 'such': 1, 'that': 1, 'papers': 1, 'eyes': 1, 'antique': 1, 'age': 2, 'were': 2, 'fresh': 1, 'lies': 1, 'than': 1, 'poet': 1, 'termed': 1, 'old': 1, 'touches': 1, 'and': 5, 'but': 2, 'some': 1, 'of': 4, 'time': 2, 'touched': 1, 'twice': 1, 'will': 1, 'yellowed': 1, 'you': 1, 'though': 1, 'heaven': 1, 'poets': 1, 'truth': 1, 'who': 1, 'i': 1, 'faces': 1, 'which': 1, 'scorned': 1, 'shows': 1, 'filled': 1, 'your': 6, 'true': 1, 'as': 1}
```

How do I go by making each key-value pair ordered alphabetically by the key?

I tried doing:

```
for key,value in sorted(freqs.items()):
        freqs[key]=value
```

but that doesn't do anything. I want it to look like this:
ab 5
and 8
...
yours 2

Comment: Use `collections.OrderedDict` (assuming you will not keep inserting keys)...

Answer (score 3):

Dicts are not sorted data structures, but you can traverse them in a sorted manner using:

```
for key in sorted(freqs.keys()):
        print freqs[key]
```

Comment: You can remove the `.keys()` call.

Comment: Nitpicking is StackOverflow :)

Comment: @JoséTomásTocino Iteration over a dict always returns its keys, so there's nothing implicit about that.

Comment: If it were preferable to use `keys()` when iterating over the keys, `for key in freqs` wouldn't be a thing that exists.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.OrderedDict` is for this purpose. [Example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes):

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

Comment: Dictionary keys are always unique, so the `key` function is not required.

Comment: This preserves the order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python are unsorted by nature. If you were to call a dictionary twice in two different places, you can expect them to be in a different order. Unless I am understanding something wrong?

Comment: should I make it into just strings?

Comment: I'm not too experienced with this, but I assume you could make two lists, one containing the numbers and the other containing the words in the same location as the word, and then sort accordingly. But there is probably a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treap
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/red-black-tree-mod

The treap is a hybrid of a tree and a heap.  It works like a sorted (by key) dictionary.

The red-black tree is a tree.  It also works like a sorted, by key, dictionary.

Some say treaps are faster than red-black trees on average, but that treaps have a greater standard deviation in operation times.

Both of them do almost everything in O(logn) time, except sorting.  They both keep everything sorted by key, nonstop.

Sometimes it's better to sort the keys of a standard dictionary, but it's rarely a good idea to sort inside a loop.